# split big pdf into multiple smaller pdfs of different page length based on spectific string appearance in the big pdf using python

Tags: python, pdf, split

**Problem**

I have a long PDF file with many pages. I want that this pdf is splitted in many smaller files, which lenght is derived from the text content of the long pdf. You can imagine the string as something that activate a scissors that cut the long pdf and give even the filename to the smaller pdf.

The "scissors" strings are generated by the following iterator and are represented from "text":

```
for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
    text = f'PANORAMICA DI {municipality.upper()}'
```

If I print ('text') in the iterator the result is that:

```
PANORAMICA DI BELLINZONA
PANORAMICA DI RIVIERA
PANORAMICA DI BLENIO
PANORAMICA DI ACQUAROSSA
```

The strings above are unique values, they appear only once.
Above I have shown only the first four, there are more and EVERY item is written in the original pdf that I want to split. Every item appears only one time in the original pdf, no more than one, no less than one (match always one to one) and in the pdf there is never additional "PANORAMICA DI........" that is not already an item obtained by the iteration. PANORAMICA means OVERVIEW in English.

Here an example of the pages inside the original pdf where there is the string that come from item "PANORAMICA DI BLENIO"
[image]

What I want to do: I want to split the original pdf every time that appears the string item.
In the image above the original pdf have to be split in two: first pdf end in the page before "PANORAMICA DI BLENIO", second begins in page "PANORAMICA DI BLENIO" and will end in the page before the next "PANORAMICA DI {municipality.upper()}". The resulting pdf name is "zp_Blenio.pdf" for the second, for the first "zp_Acquarossa". For this it should be no problem because "municipality" when it is no upper() is already OK (in other words is "Acquarossa" and "Blenio")

Other example to understand with a simplified simulation (my file has more page):
original pdf 12 pages long, pay attention that is not a code, but I put as a code to write well:

```
page 1: "PANORAMICA DI RIVIERA"
page 2: no match with "text" item
page 3: no match with "text" item 
page 4: "PANORAMICA DI ACQUAROSSA"
page 5: no match with "text" item 
page 6: "PANORAMICA DI BLENIO"
page 7: no match with "text" item 
page 8: no match with "text" item
page 9: no match with "text" item 
page 10: no match with "text" item
page 11: "PANORAMICA DI BELLINZONA"
page 12: no match with "text" item
```

results will be (again pay attention that is not a code, but I put as a code to show you well):

```
first created pdf is from page 1 to page 3
second created pdf is from page 4 to page 5
third pdf is from page 6 to 10
forth pdf is from page 11 to 12
```

the rule is like: split at the page when a text appears until the page before that the text appears again, split at the page when a text appears until the page before that the text appears again, and so on.

Take care: my original pdf is part of a long py code and the pdf changed every time, but the rule of "PANORAMICA DI ....." does not change. In other words, maybe the interval lenght of pages between "PANORAMICA DI ACQUAROSSA" and "PANORAMICA DI BLENIO" changes. This prevents to use a workaroung and set manually the interval of page to split ignoring the rules established above.

**Attempt to solve the problem**

The only one solution to this issue that I have found is a code that was obsolete and not checked by the author that can be found in this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62344714/13769033

I've taken the code and changed depending on the new functions and classes and integrating the iteration to obtain "text".

The result of the old code after my updating is the following:

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader
import re

def getPagebreakList(file_name: str)->list:
    pdf_file = PyPDF2.PdfReader(file_name)
    num_pages = len(pdf_file.pages)
    page_breaks = list()
    for i in range(0, num_pages):
        Page = pdf_file.pages[i] 
        Text = PageObject.extract_text() 
        for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
            text = f'PANORAMICA DI {municipality.upper()}'
            if re.search(text, Text):
                page_breaks.append(i)
    return page_breaks


inputpdf = PdfReader(open("./report1.pdf", "rb"))
num_pages = len(inputpdf.pages)
page_breaks = getPagebreakList("./report1.pdf")

i = 0
while (i < num_pages):
    if page_breaks:
        page_break = page_breaks.pop(0)
    else:
        page_break = num_pages
    output = PdfWriter()
    while (i != page_break + 1):
        output.add_page(inputpdf.pages[i])
        i = i + 1
    with open(Path('.')/f'zp_{municipality}.pdf',"wb") as outputStream:
        output.write(outputStream)
```

Unfortunately, I don't understand large part of the code.

From the part that I don't understand at all and I don't know if the author made an error:

- the indentation of "output = PdfWriter()"
- the "getPagebreakList('./report1.pdf')" where I put the same pdf that I want to split but where tha author put "getPagebreakList('**yourPDF.pdf**')" that was nevertheless different of PdfFileReader(open("**80....pdf**", "rb")). I assume that it should have written **yourPDF.pdf** for both.

To be noted: "./report1.pdf" is the path where there is the pdf to split and I am sure that is right.

The code is wrong, when I execute I obtain "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable".

I want that someone help me to find the solution. You can modified my updated code or suggest another way to solve. Thank you.

**Suggestion to simulate**

To simplify, at the beginning I suggest to consider a static string of your pdf (strings that is repeating every x pages) instead of part of an array.

In my case, I had considered:

```
Text = PageObject.extract_text() 
text = 'PANORAMICA'
if re.search(text, Text):
    page_breaks.append(i)
```

....and changed even the path for the output.

You can simply use a long pdf with repeating fixed text that appears periodically but in an irregular way (once after 3 pages, once every 5 pages and so on).

Only when you find the solution you can integrate the iteration for municipality. The integration of "municipality" on the text is only used to integrate the "municipality" in the name of the new pdf files. Using only "PANORAMICA" does not impact on the lenght of the page interval of the new pdf.

Comment: There is smt strange with the file name for the writer, `municipality` is not defined. Does municipality refer to the string in the previous function? In case a dictionary (and not a list) could be the right way: `{'municipality_x1': page2, 'municipality_x2': page6, }`

Comment: Could you give an example of file name? For _RIVIERA_ are you expecting a file with 3 pages called `zp_RIVERA.pdf`?

Comment: @cards municipality cannot be reproduced by you, municipality is created from a geoservice WFS vetor in QGIS. It comes from previous function.  It is right that you obtain that is not defined. For this reason I suggest to follow "Suggestion to simulate" ignoring the iteration, making text='PANORAMICA'. 

I expect "zp_Riviera" that is given by f'zp_{municipality}.pdf. But again, does not focus on the name at this steph.

Comment: the rule is like: split at the page when a text appears until the page before that the text appears again, split at the page when a text appears until the page before that the text appears again, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to divide the problem into smaller ones, essentially using a *divide and conquer* approach. By making single task functions debugging in case of mistakes should be easier. Notice that `getPagebreakList` is slightly different.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfWriter, PdfReader


def page_breaks(pdf_r:PdfReader) -> dict:
    p_breaks = {}
    for i in range(len(pdf_r.pages)):
        page_text = pdf_r.pages[i].extract_text() 
        for municipality in array_merged_zone_send:
            pattern = f'PANORAMICA DI {municipality.upper()}'
            if re.search(pattern, page_text):
                p_breaks[municipality] = i
    return p_breaks
 

def filenames_range_mapper(pdf_r:PdfReader, page_indices:dict) -> dict:
    num_pages = list(page_indices.values()) + [len(pdf_r.pages)+1] # add last page as well
    # slice the pages from the reader object
    return {name: pdf_r.pages[start:end] for name, start, end in zip(page_indices, num_pages, num_pages[1:])}


def save(file_name:str, pdf_pages:list[PdfReader]) -> None:
    # pass the pages to the writer
    pdf_w = PdfWriter()
    for p in pdf_pages:
        pdf_w.add_page(p)
    
    # write to file
    with open(file_name, "wb") as outputStream:
        pdf_w.write(outputStream) 
    
    # message
    print(f'Pdf "{file_name}" created.')


# main
# ####
# initial location of the file
file_name = "./report1.pdf"
# create reader object
pdf_r = PdfReader(open(file_name, "rb"))
# get index locations of matches
p_breaks = page_breaks(pdf_r)
# dictionary of name-pages slice objects
mapper = filenames_range_mapper(pdf_r, p_breaks)

# template file name
template_output = './zp_{}.pdf'
# iterate over the location-pages mapper
for municipality, pages in mapper.items():
    # set file name
    new_file_name = template_output.format(municipality.title()) # eventually municipality.upper()
    # save the pages into a new file
    save(new_file_name, pages)
```

---

Test the code with auxiliary function to avoid unwanted output.

In this case it would be enough to consider a slightly different implementation of `filenames_range_mapper` in which the values will be just a list of integers (and not `PdfReader` objects).

```
def filenames_range_mapper_tester(pdf_r:PdfReader, page_indices:dict) -> dict:
    num_pages = list(page_indices.values()) + [len(pdf_r.pages)+1] # add last page as well
    # slice the pages from the reader object
    return {name: list(range(len(pdf_r.pages)+1))[start:end] for name, start, end in zip(page_indices, num_pages, num_pages[1:])}

# auxiliary test
file_name = "./report1.pdf"
pdf_r = PdfReader(open(file_name, "rb"))
p_breaks = page_breaks(pdf_r)
mapper = filenames_range_mapper_tester(pdf_r, p_breaks)

template_output = './zp_{}.pdf'
for name, pages in mapper.items():
   print(template_output.format(name.title()), pages)
```

If the output make sense then you can proceed with the non-testing code.

---

An **abstraction** on how to get the right pages:

```
# mimic return of "page_breaks"
page_breaks = {
    "RIVIERA": 1,
    "ACQUAROSSA": 4,
    "BLENIO": 6,
    "BELLINZONA": 11
}

# mimic "filenames_range_mapper"
last_page_of_pdf = 12 + 1 # increment by 1 the number of pages of the pdf!

num_pages = list(page_breaks.values()) + [last_page_of_pdf]
#[1, 4, 6, 11, 12]

mapper = {name: list(range(start, end)) for name, start, end in zip(page_breaks, num_pages, num_pages[1:])}
#{'RIVIERA': [1, 2, 3],
# 'ACQUAROSSA': [4, 5],
# 'BLENIO': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
# 'BELLINZONA': [11, 12]}
```

Comment: I haven't tested so in case of mistakes let know and I will fix (please add full error traceback)

Comment: first question about your answer: in the code is written num_pages = list(mapper_pages.values()) + [len(pdf_r.pages)]. Where come from mapper_pages? How can create a list if mapper_pages is not defined before?

Comment: second question about your answer: why do you define in abstraction num_pages = list(page_breaks.values()) + [last_page_of_pdf], do you mean that page_breaks is the same of mapper_pages e [last_page_of_pdf] is the same of [len(pdf_r.pages)]??

Comment: last question about you answer: if really [last_page_of_pdf]=[len(pdf_r.pages)] why do you  tell [last_page_of_pdf]=13, you write 12+1? For me [len(pdf_r.pages)] should be 12, the formula give 12, cannot give the result 13. @cards

Comment: 1) edited the code, it was a copy-paste typo 2) yes, it is a minimal working example 3) Just make a test:) it should be `+1` otherwise for Bellinzona you will get a single page and not 2

Comment: ok, tomorrow I will test your code. I still don't understand how [len(pdf_r.pages)] can be one page more than the object that calculates the lenght. I will look at the test if will be one more than the real lenght. You look like very experienced, maybe you have right

Comment: because the slice "eats" the upper bound, `range(11, 13)` -> `11, 12`, that's why 1 more is needed. In a slice the difference between the boundaries is the amount terms,`13-11` -> `2`

Comment: @simone100 I fixed many(!) small bugs and now should be ok (by clicking at _edit_ in the bottom-middle of my answer you can see the changes)

Comment: I have tested and there are some errors.  In my case the results are: the pdf of Riviera does not exist instead of having a pdf from p.1 to 3, as first pdf is zp_Acquarossa from p.3 to 4 instead of p.4 to 5, then Blenio p.5 to 9 instead of p.6 to 10 and then zp_Bellinzona from p.10 to 12 instead of p.11 to 12.

Comment: The code works I tested using also the `page_breaks` function... and I didn't get the right result not because of the code but because of the text extraction step. It happens that text extraction is not very reliable. In my test I took a random pdf from the web (perfect quality!) and I took a slice of the 1st line of some chapters... and after going mad a bit I looked at the extracted text and there was the problem! PyPdf returns `Besides thewhilestatement just introduced,` but the pattern passed to `re.search` has right spaces... and if there is no match there is no page break!

Comment: add an `else` branch to `page_breaks` with a `print(pattern, page_text)` to inspect the extracted text

Comment: see [doc](https://pypdf2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/extract-text.html#why-text-extraction-is-hard) for details about text extraction

Comment: so, if I understand the result also depends from the PDF type, maybe the way that has been built. And there is no solution to solve if the result is not what you want. @cards

Comment: sadly, yes. Try to extract the text of pdf written for example into 2 columns:) It's hard to do smoothly in one shot. Ideally try to inspect 1 or 2 pages to check for irregularities and, in case, try to fix them and then extend to the full document. In this case could be useful to improve the `else`-part to understand what went wrong (with a simple `print` or by `raise Exception("No match for xyz")`). It could happen that you can fix the match by using _regex_ as well. There is another way that maybe could work: OCR -> pytesseract